# Rename [gradle-kotlin-dsl] Tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

The Gradle build tool has two languages that build definitions can be written in, Groovy & Kotlin.  There are corresponding tags for each:

- [build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build.gradle)
- [gradle-kotlin-dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle-kotlin-dsl)

There is an asymmetry with the tags that we'd like to resolve to make it more clear that these tags are about the respective build definition languages.  Here is an example question where you can see the asymmetry:
[All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Please rename the [gradle-kotlin-dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle-kotlin-dsl) to [build.gradle.kts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build.gradle.kts) (a current synonym) and make sure that [gradle-kotlin-dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle-kotlin-dsl) remains a synonym for [build.gradle.kts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build.gradle.kts).

Comment: I'm an adamant user of Gradle and I have never thought of calling build.gradle the Groovy DSL before.  My big concern is that the cardinality of this synonym request is backwards and you may get more user confusion from it rather than less.

Comment: This does seem to highlight the confusion which proper tag names can help resolve.  build.gradle is the Groovy DSL but often times users don't realize that.

Comment: I think it's less about realization and more about how it's referred to in casual/typical day-to-day work.  I just feel very strongly that the cardinality of your synonym request is backwards.  Most developers refer to the Groovy DSL through "build.gradle".  Even if it's using Kotlin, showing a "build.gradle" will usually result in someone producing the right file.  I just don't personally see the benefit in reversing the relationship, and given the tag counts, I don't think there's a lot of people who do, either.

Comment: There is a lot of user confusion over the relationship between the build file and the build language and we are actively trying to reduce that confusion through more clarity of that relationship.  Alternatively we could rename the `gradle-kotlin-dsl` tag to `build.gradle.kts` with a synonym to `gradle-kotlin-dsl`.  However, the initially proposed way makes it more clear that `build.gradle` is about the Groovy DSL.

Comment: Example evidence of confusion: https://twitter.com/martinbonnin/status/1580158851495923715

Comment: ...but that doesn't have anything to do about how we ask the question.  This smells like a documentation issue that should be fixed in official documentation more than a symptom of how people ask questions about it.  The build.gradle file will always be the build.gradle file, and the only real difference will be whether or not someone is writing in Kotlin as opposed to Groovy (which is presumed to be the default).  I guess...the tricky thing is just that I've never heard anyone ask questions about "the Groovy DSL" without it being in context to build.gradle before.

Comment: All that to say I think that the Kotlin synonym makes a lot of sense, but I don't see it making any sense for one you're proposing.

Comment: If someone asks about `build.gradle` they are asking about the Groovy DSL. If someone asks about the Groovy DSL they are asking about `build.gradle`. Likewise if someone asks about `build.gradle.kts` they are asking about the Kotlin DSL. And if someone asks about the Kotlin DSL, they are asking about `build.gradle.kts`. I think it makes sense to make the primary tags the more explicit form (`gradle-groovy-dsl` and `gradle-kotlin-dsl`). If we want to go the other way and make the primary tags file based (`build.gradle` and `build.gradle.kts`) that is better than the asymmetry that exists today.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with this.  The asymmetry is a natural consequence to how people ask their question .  Having this synonym go `build.gradle -> gradle-groovy-dsl` will confuse a whole lot of people looking to get help with their build.gradle scripts, because they don't care if it's Groovy or not, they care that they have an issue with their build.gradle script.

Comment: The whole point is that they need to care because they can't put Kotlin into `build.gradle` and can't put Groovy into `build.gradle.kts`.  But I see your point that many users don't really know or care what the language is so they tag their question with `build.gradle` because that is the file they are editing.  Don't tag synonyms solve this for us though?  ie. after my proposed change tagging a question `build.gradle` would change it on save to `gradle-groovy-dsl` similar to how today tagging `build.gradle.kts` changes it to `gradle-kotlin-dsl` on save.

Comment: I don't think it does.  Learning the right way to refer to these different DSLs is a *consequence* to asking the question, not a *prerequisite*.  Tagging questions on Stack Overflow, in my view, indicates that there's some kind of common convention that is understood to be something, and synonymizing conventions together indicate that these conventions are equivalent.  But what we *don't* want to do is to lose the thing that makes us come back to the root convention.  The confidence to answer or engage will shrink, somewhat noticeably.

Comment: Like, I can tell the difference between Groovy and "not Groovy" pretty quickly.  So that's when one tags the question with `build.gradle` and `kotlin`, although it might be *preferable* to tag it with `gradle-kotlin-dsl` (but then I couldn't guarantee that someone with passing Kotlin knowledge wouldn't know an answer to it).  But bluntly and firmly, the `build.gradle` file is the same in terms of its convention, regardless of what DSL it's using.  If I had explicit and narrow questions about the DSL *itself*, then sure, I could see tagging it with `gradle-groovy-dsl`.  But few do.

Comment: Ultimately this response is more based out of my own conventions and personal interactions with the tool.  If Gradle wants to officially start documenting the differences and change the convention, then I am of the firm opinion that it should start *there* and make its way to Stack Overflow *organically*.

Comment: The docs do use `build.gradle` and `build.gradle.kts` to indicate the different DSLs already, like: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

To be more consistent with the docs I've flipped the request to instead rename `gradle-kotlin-dsl` to `build.gradle.kts`.

Comment: Okay; I can get behind this now!